# Are foreign keys mandatory in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, navicat

Do I need to assign a foreign key in MySQL?

(Navicat for MySQL, PHP, I'm programming a social network for sake of fun)

Comment: You don't need to do anything. We need more details..

Comment: What is the purpose of foreign key? I thought that it is imaginary concept.

Comment: Data integrity for instance? Including cascade for updates and deletions...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

Comment: For some systems, such as PostgreSQL and some of the engines in MySQL, it can be absolutely required, and enforced as a constraint. You don't *need* to define a foreign key normally in MySQL, but having one structurally (i.e. a link between two tables) is the basis of relational database systems.

Comment: *imaginary concept?* i actually laughed out loud when i read that comment.

Comment: Do we need to downvote him like hell just because of his naive wording? English is not everyone's mother tongue here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/2248101/Referential-Integrity-in-MySQL.htm

> You can 'define' a foreign key in any
>   MySQL table type (including the
>   default MyISAM table type), but they
>   do not actually do anything - they are
>   only used to enforce referential
>   integrity in InnoDB tables.

The OP should be excused to think it is an "imaginary" concept.

Comment: +1 @fredt, nice find - only because it would make someone who doesn't have an in-depth knowledge of database mechanics to think that foreign keys have no practical use.

Comment: Minor note.  That's not database mechanics; that is bottom rung, freeware database mechanics.